# htaccess redirect to parent folder index.php if does not exist

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

I'm building a web api via php.  One of the things I'm struggling with is setting up the htaccess file to redirect to index.php of the parent folder when something does not exist.  My folder structure looks like this:

```
/SkedApi/
    index.php
    /Users/
        index.php
```

This is what I have so far, but it isn't working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Currently if it doesn't exist it redirects it all the way back to `/SkedApi/index.php`.  But in the case of `/Users/3` I need it to redirect to `/Users/index.php`.  `/Users/` works correctly and directs it to `/Users/index.php`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use absolute paths:

```
RewriteRule ^Users/(.*)$ /Users/index.php [NC,L]
```

for users and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

for the rest.

Comment: You need the parenthesis in the regexp if you want to reuse that. Like this: `RewriteRule ^User/(.*)$ /User/index.php?uid=$1 [NC,L]` Unless yo can go for the simple ^User/

Edit: if you want to implement some kind of controller logic, you can catch them with regexps.

Considering your controller is a single word:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)$ /Users/index.php?mycontroler=$1&mydata=$2 [NC,L]
```

of course you can omit $1 $2 if your framework gets this info from the query string directly.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) /Users/index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Surely there has to be a general/better way to solve this.  That seems very error-prone to have to edit the htaccess file every time I add a new controller.

Comment: @gotoguru, yes my framework gets that from the query string.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the regexp. The first one ate up all the string. Fixed. I'm assuming here your are using one word controllers.

Comment: @keelerjr12 Or maybe you want that, *iff* your controller directory exists then redirect to controller/index.php otherwise redirect to root/index.php ?